# VBA & Power Query to pull excel sheet from a password-protected website

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Part of my work involves financial modelling. For this, we use forecast interest rates, published by Chatham Financial (https://www.chathamfinancial.com/).

They used to publish the data on a spreadsheet located a non-login protected section of their website, which a simply Power Query could pull easily.

Now, however, they have moved to a new website setup which is password protected. We have an account, but the way the website is set up is (I think) defeating the Power Query.

The username entry for the website is here: https://www.chathamdirect.com/login

Once the username is entered, the URL then moves to another page for the password: https://www.chathamdirect.com/login/password

After some digging, I've found the URL for the excel sheet that can then be downloaded via the same URL every day (even though the file name changes each day): https://chathamdirect.com/rates/api/v1/rateset/sonia/forwardcurves/export/

Once I've logged into the website, I can download the sheet simply by pasting this link into the browser. However, this is quite a manually-intensive way of doing it, and defeats the point of having a Power Query.

Is there a way of negotiating the two-page login process, and then downloading the file from the URL above (while remaining logged in)?

Any help would be gratefully received!

Best wishes all.

I have tried using the login credentials within Power Query, but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really a two page login. You will need to use a tool like postman together with browser Developer Tools. With browser Developer Tools, you can inspect the Network traffic.

For example, after entering the password and clicking on `Log in`, you can see a POST request made to `https://chathamdirect.com/authentication/api/v1/login/authenticate`  with his payload:

```json
{
    "username": "tester Username",
    "password": "tester Password",
    "skipImpersonation": "",
    "redirectUrl": ""
}
```

Next, you need to see what the response is of the above request, and how the authentication is done. Is it by cookie, by header etc... Only you can do this part (as we don't have login credentials).

Then try to replicate the same via Postman (or similar tool). Two requests: POST to login and get the authentication token, and then a (mostly likely) a GET to get the file with the authentication token in the request. Once you can achieve that, then you can replicate in Power Query.

Once you get to this point, you can replicate the same in PowerQuery, by first doing the same POST request with the login credentials (JSON payload), then capturing the authentication cookie/header. Then make the second request to the file with the same authentication cookie/header in the request.